# unicode (utf8) writing (Arabic, Hebrew,chines) to files in the cloud storage, Python

Tags: file, google-app-engine, python-2.7, utf-8, google-cloud-storage

I would like to write to a file in multiple language and after then store it in the cloud storage.this my code:

```
file=gcs.open(filename,'w',content_type='text/html; charset=utf-8')

      file.write(str(content))
      file.close()
```

How could I modify it ?
thank you

Comment: If content has utf-8, use content.encode('utf-8') to make it binary. More info: http://blog.notdot.net/2010/07/Getting-unicode-right-in-Python

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looks like this might be an issue of encoding your string as UTF-8 before calling `file.write`. How about:

```
file.write(content.encode('utf-8'))
```